# NumPy Array Indexing

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

Simple question here about indexing an array to get a subset of its values.  Say I have a `recarray` which holds ages in one space, and corresponding values in another.  I also have an array which is my desired subset of ages.  Here is what I mean:

```
ages = np.arange(100)
values = np.random.uniform(low=0, high= 1, size = ages.shape)
data = np.core.rec.fromarrays([ages, values], names='ages,values')
desired_ages = np.array([1,4, 16, 29, 80])
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
data.values[data.ages==desired_ages]
```

But, it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create an subarray containing only the values whose indexes are in `desired_ages`.

Python doesn't have any syntax that directly corresponds to this, but list comprehensions can do a pretty nice job:

```
result = [value for index, value in enumerate(data.values) if index in desired_ages]
```

However, doing it this way results in Python scanning through `desired_ages` for each element in `data.values`, which is slow. If you could insert

```
desired_ages = set(desired_ages)
```

on the line before, this would improve performance. (You can determine if a value in is a set in constant time, regardless of the set's size.)

---

#### Complete Example

```
import numpy as np

ages = np.arange(100)
values = np.random.uniform(low=0, high= 1, size = ages.shape)
data = np.core.rec.fromarrays([ages, values], names='ages,values')
desired_ages = np.array([1,4, 16, 29, 80])

result = [value for index, value in enumerate(data.values) if index in desired_ages]
print result
```

Output

```
[0.45852624094611272, 0.0099713014816563694, 0.26695859251958864, 0.10143425810157047, 0.93647796171383935]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable first approach:

```
>>> bool_indices = reduce(numpy.logical_or, 
                          (data.ages == x for x in desired_ages))
>>> data.values[bool_indices]
array([ 0.63143784,  0.93852927,  0.0026815 ,  0.66263594,  0.2603184 ])
```

But that uses python functions, so it's probably slower. We can translate it pretty easily into pure numpy, using `ix_` to make the arrays broadcast against each other nicely. (`meshgrid` with swapped arguments would work too, but would use more memory.):

```
>>> bools_2d = numpy.equal(*numpy.ix_(desired_ages, data.ages))
>>> bool_indices = numpy.logical_or.reduce(bools_2d)
>>> data.ages[bool_indices]
array([ 1,  4, 16, 29, 80])
>>> data.values[bool_indices]
array([ 0.32324063,  0.65453647,  0.9300062 ,  0.34534668,  0.12151951])
```

See also [HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003477/577088)'s answer for a potentially faster solution (using `searchsorted`) and a potentially more readable solution (using `in1d`).

Answer (score 2):

I changed your example a little, shuffle the order of ages:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
ages = np.arange(3,103)
np.random.shuffle(ages)
values = np.random.uniform(low=0, high= 1, size = ages.shape)
data = np.core.rec.fromarrays([ages, values], names='ages,values')
desired_ages = np.array([4, 16, 29, 80])
```

If all the elements of desired_ages are in data.ages, you can sort data by age field first, and then use searchsorted() to find all the index quickly:

```
data.sort(order="ages") # sort by ages
print data.values[np.searchsorted(data.ages, desired_ages)]
```

or you can use np.in1d the get a bool array and use it as index:

```
print data.values[np.in1d(data.ages, desired_ages)]
```