# Python list as a list indices

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have two lists

```
list_A = [1,3,4,54,3,5,6,2,6,77,73,39]
list_B = [0,3,2,8]
```

I want to access elements of `list_A` that have the values in `list_B` as their indices (without using loops).

After implementing it, the result should be as follows for the above case:

```
[1, 54, 4, 6]
```

Is there any easy method to do this without bothering with `for` loops (calling it explicitly in the code) ?

Comment: Slightly related if you're going the numpy path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002895/numpy-array-indexing

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by a `for-loop`. The obvious way to do it is with a list comprehension. Does `[A[x] for x in B]` use a `for-loop`? Maybe. Does `map(lambda i: list_A[i], list_B)`? No `for-loop` in sight, but there is iteration in `map`. How about numpy solutions? No iteration visible, but ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything will use a loop internally*, but it doesn't have to be as complicated as you might think. You can try a list comprehension:

```
[list_A[i] for i in list_B]
```

Alternatively, you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
list(operator.itemgetter(*list_B)(list_A))
```

---

```
>>> import operator
>>> list_A = [1,3,4,54,3,5,6,2,6,77,73,39]
>>> list_B = [0,3,2,8]
>>> [list_A[i] for i in list_B]
[1, 54, 4, 6]
>>> list(operator.itemgetter(*list_B)(list_A))
[1, 54, 4, 6]
```

---

******* OK! Maybe you don't need a loop with recursion, but I think it's definately overkill for something like this.

Comment: Which uses a loop. But the requirement that you don't use a loop is insane.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Everything will, at its core, use a loop.

Comment: @A.R.S.: Of course, the numpy solutions use loops too, internally. As I said, the stated requirement is not attainable.

Comment: My intention is not to call a loop explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: @A.R.S.: "...unless it uses recursion."

Answer (score 3):

## Recursion answer

No iteration/loops here. Just recursion.

```
>>> list_A = [1,3,4,54,3,5,6,2,6,77,73,39]
>>> list_B = [0,3,2,8]
>>> def foo(src, indexer):
...     if not indexer:
...         return []
...     else:
...         left, right = indexer[0], indexer[1:]
...         return [src[left]] + foo(src, right)
... 
>>> foo(list_A, list_B)
[1, 54, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using numpy, you can do the following:

```
list_A[list_B]  // yields [1, 54, 4, 6]
```

Edit: As Nick T pointed out, don't forget to convert to arrays first!

Comment: Lists should be converted to arrays before doing this, right?

Comment: list_A should be. list_B doesn't have to be. `arr_A = np.array(list_A)`

Answer (score 2):

## map answer

```
>>> list_A = [1,3,4,54,3,5,6,2,6,77,73,39]
>>> list_B = [0,3,2,8]
>>> map(lambda i: list_A[i], list_B)
[1, 54, 4, 6]
```

## Disclaimer

I don't think this technically meets the requirement that there be no `for-loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy can do this with [its indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in a fairly straightforward manner.  Convert the list to an array then you're gold.  You can pass any sort of iterable as indices.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> list_A = [1,3,4,54,3,5,6,2,6,77,73,39]
>>> list_B = [0,3,2,8]
>>> numpy.array(list_A)[list_B]
array([ 1, 54,  4,  6])
```